# what is the semantically correct way to create an accordion widget?

Tags: html, semantics

taking into account the semantic web and HTML5, what is the **semantically correct** way to create an accordion widget?

example:

jQueryUI proposes the following example:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

now if it is clear that we need a list that has a title and content, now that is what we would need then:

a list of definitions?

```
<dl>
    <dt>
       Title
    </dt>
    <dd>
       Content
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I'm torn about whether questions like these should go to SO. [Are questions about semantic HTML on topic?](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/523/are-questions-about-semantic-html-on-topic)

Comment: Unless there's a strong case that the implementation will significantly affect usability or accessibility, code questions should sit firmly in Stack Overflow

Comment: this question must be migrate to StackOverflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semantics are based on the **content**.

not the style,
not the interaction.

Because of this, there isn't going to be just one way to markup an accordion widget semantically. As an accordion widget is an *interaction*.

`dl`'s should be used for [name-value groups](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), so it would be semantic to use a dl with an accordion widget if you've got "terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.":

```
<dl id="definitions">
  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>
  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>
  ...
</dl>
```

If you've got a bunch of articles in an archive, it could be semantic to use:

```
<h1>Archive</h1>
<div id="articles">
  <h2>...</h2>
  <article>...</article>
  <h2>...</h2>
  <article>...</article>
  ...
</div>
```

Before worrying about what the content should do, figure out what your content *is*.